# Automatically Deleting empty MySQL rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a system that gives users auth codes, however sometimes the system malfunctions, and puts an empty row in the table. How can i check upon creation if a part of the row is empty "" and how to automatically delete it each time? Im kind of new so some detailed help would be great. I have researched it a bit just can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: Why not just ... don't put an empty row in the database?

Comment: isn't it better to fix the code?

Comment: Yeah actually i was able to fix it so this question is useless now, Sorry

Comment: @PavlovaBaker If you solved your question please post your own answer and close your question

Answer (score 2):

You haven't supplied any detail about your table but the normal syntax would be:

```
DELETE FROM myTable WHERE columnName='';
```